# Consultar datos de una tabla con IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

No se como realizar la consulta para que en lugar de que me traigo el Id_Empresa y Id_Contactos, me traiga de la tabla de Empresas el campo Empresa y de la tabla de contactos me traiga el campo Contactos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has probado ?

Comment: Que has intentado? Por favor edita y añade tu consulta

Comment: Intente unir las tablas con JOIN pero no me trae el Id: Id_Empresas_Contactos de la Tabla empresas_contactos. Realice la siguiente consulta: SELECT e.Empresa, c.Contacto FROM empresas e INNER JOIN contactos c ON e.Id=c.Id    (pero no es lo que busco)

Comment: SELECT e.Fecha, e.Empresa, e,Estado, e.Municipio FROM empresas_contactos AS ec INNER JOIN empresas AS e ON e.id = ec.Id_Empresas

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener los valores de las tablas que participan en una relación de muchos a muchos debes unir la tabla "empresas" con la tabla de muchos a muchos "empresas_contactos" y por ultimo unirla con la tabla "contactos".

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Fecha, e.Empresa, e.Estado, 
c.Id, c.Fecha, c.Contacto, c.puesto 
FROM empresas AS e INNER JOIN empresas_contactos AS ec 
ON e.Id = ec.Id_Empresas INNER JOIN contactos AS c 
ON ec.Id_Contactos = c.Id;
```

Comment: Es correcta tu respuesta, pero tiene errores: `SELEC` en vez de **`SELECT`**. También falta poner el prefijo aquí: `ON e.Id = Id_Empresas`, debería ser: **`ON e.Id = ec.Id_Empresas`**. También, identa mejor tu código, es confuso como estás identando, esto en la misma línea es horrible: `ON e.Id = ec.Id_Empresas INNER JOIN contactos AS c `

Comment: Gracias a los Dos